# Recursividade- elemindices

Tags: haskell

Sabem como definir recursivamente a função elemindices, pré-definida na Prelude.
Eu defini de uma forma, mas não dá o resultado esperado.

```
myElemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
myElemIndices x [] = []
myElemIndices x (h:t) | x == h = 0 : myElemIndices x t
                      | otherwise = myElemIndices x t
```

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: elemIndices 3 [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5] corresponde a [2,4,6].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou explicar duas formas que funcionam mas não sei se é realmente o que você deseja:

```
myElemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
myElemIndices x [] = []
myElemIndices a xs = indexed a (zip xs [0..])
    where indexed _ [] = [] 
          indexed a ((x,i):xs) 
              | x == a = i:indexed a xs
              | otherwise = indexed a xs
```

Estou usando uma função interna chamada indexed que atribui índices à lista usando a função zip. Essa função retorna tuplas com a união das listas, no caso fica (x1, 1), (x2, 2) ... (xn , n). A cada rodada recursiva em que a igualdade x == a é verdadeira eu faço o append do índice no resultado. (Veja no [repl.it](https://repl.it/Mpks/1) - créditos ao autor: [Counting positions in a list haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636782/counting-positions-in-a-list-haskell))

Ou pode fazer uso de uma função auxiliar diferente:

```
myElemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
myElemIndices x [] = []
myElemIndices x xs = count 0 x xs

count :: Eq a => Int -> a -> [a] -> [Int]
count c x [] = []
count c x (y:ys)
   | x == y = c:count (c+1) x ys
   | otherwise = count (c+1) x ys
```

No caso acima eu uso uma função com um argumento a mais para contar. Quando x = y ele da um append no contador atual e passa adiante com contador + 1. (Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/Mpks/0))

Comment: Muito Obrigado, era isso mesmo o que pretendia :)

Comment: Poderia marcar a resposta como aceita? Tem um OK verde ali embaixo das setas ^ | v